# Does a Category applied to NSString also apply to NSCFString via the "toll-free bridge"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, categories, google-toolbox-for-mac

We're integrating a library into an iPhone app which appears to use the google toolbox for iPhone internally.
The google toolbox adds a method `gtm_stringBySanitizingAndEscapingForXML` to NSString.
The problem is, whenever we attempt to make a call to this library we get

`[NSCFString gtm_stringBySanitizingAndEscapingForXML]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x272478`

So it appears the library is calling that method on a NSCFString, to which the category does not apply. 
So... is it the case that the category will not apply across the toll-free bridge to CoreFoundation classes?
If that's the case then we at least know why it's blowing up. Figuring out how to fix it is a different matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Categories applied to NSString do apply to NSCFString as well, because NSCFString is a subclass of NSMutableString which is a subclass of NSString.

But have you actually included the Google Toolbox library (`GTMNSString+XML.m`)?

Comment: The google toolbox is built into the library, so if we include it we get errors because of classes be re-defined.
My co-worker has actually solved the problem, there was a linker flag that caused it to break.
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

`NSCFString` class is not a subclass of `NSMutableString`... It's just another class of `NSString` cluster. So if you have a `NSCFString` foo var and you test this:

```
BOOL isNSString = [foo isKindObClass:[NSString class]];
```

You will get that `isNSString` is `NO`.

I'm experiencing some problems because I've created a `NSString` category and I don't know how to apply the new methods when the class is a `NSCFString` or any other class from that cluster...

---

EDIT:
Ok, I found the solution. Although those tests returned `NO`:

```
[myString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];
[myString respondsToSelector:@selector(myNSStringCategorySelector:)];
```

I forced the execution of the method for the `NSCFString` class, and it worked correctly!!

I hope it'll help someone!

Comment: Forced the execution how? Using performSelector?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the implementation of this category is not linked into your program. Assuming that your library is compiled as a static library you might need to add the `-ObjC` linker flag to your project. For more information take a look at [this technote](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#qa/qa1490/_index.html). The linker bug mentioned in there should be fixed with the latest Xcode release.